# PHP - Accessing data inside JSON string with objects

Tags: php, json, object, parsing

Background:

I have a project to move data accessed via an API to another application. The code is in PHP and at the moment I cannot access the "url" within the returned JSON string.

```
$json = '{"data": [{"vehicle": {"id": "2122233","name": "MY REG"},"files": [{"vin": "WMARR44444W146311","createdAtTime": "2020-08-05T00:25:47.388Z","url": "https://tachograph-files43679/2020/8/5/WMA24XZZ7BW146311/1596587147388-b6785431-c2e1-41ff-b7af-9bb078654882.ddd?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-XXXXXXXXXXXXX","id": "XXXXXXXXX"}]}],"pagination": {"endCursor": "XXXXX-be93-44b2-91a2-095af9f1c301","hasNextPage": false}}';
```

Here is the JSON string (sensitive data removed).  Once I get the result I then have to use the URL in another call to retrieve the file data.

If I use json_decode($json) I get an error.

If I use jsondecode($json,true) the URL is not  accessible.

I know that the problem is an object within the JSON string but I can't figure out how to access it.

Ultimately I will have multiple vehicles and multiple files referenced in the JSON.

So, I would like to loop through the JSON and then make another call to download the data file.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks
Malcolm

Comment: `json_decode($json)` does not give an error, it generates an object

Comment: `echo $obj->data[0]->files[0]->url;`

Answer (score 1):

The JSON you've provided is fine and **doesn't** generate an error when PHP tries to decode it. You can access the URL like this:

```
$json = '{"data": [{"vehicle": {"id": "2122233","name": "MY REG"},"files": [{"vin": "WMARR44444W146311","createdAtTime": "2020-08-05T00:25:47.388Z","url": "https://tachograph-files43679/2020/8/5/WMA24XZZ7BW146311/1596587147388-b6785431-c2e1-41ff-b7af-9bb078654882.ddd?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-XXXXXXXXXXXXX","id": "XXXXXXXXX"}]}],"pagination": {"endCursor": "XXXXX-be93-44b2-91a2-095af9f1c301","hasNextPage": false}}';
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->data[0]->files[0]->url;
```

Working demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9957b8173821d91a2616981788d7d1ebde959df7

You also claimed that using `json_encode($data, true);` makes the URL inaccessible. It **doesn't**. But because that command generates an associative array instead of an object, you have to use different syntax to access it:

```
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
echo $obj["data"][0]["files"][0]["url"];
```

Working demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3d88cde32b31cffe065b7a56c2bc57f2a46fbbe8

Comment: Thank you very much.  I do struggle with multi-dimensional arrays .

Comment: @Malcolmf No problem. P.S. Conceptually I think you'd be better to think of this data as a hierarchical structure of lists and items (somewhat like a tree) than a multidimensional array.

Comment: Thanks for that advice and sorry for my ignorance... should there be multiple files to access e.g. $obj["data"][0]["files"][1]["url"] and $obj["data"][0]["files"][2]["url"]  etc.  , how would I iterate through the JSON?

Comment: well, once you've decoded it, it isn't JSON anymore, it's an array. So you iterate through it like any other array in PHP - e.g. with a `for` or `foreach` loop over the array items.